# Plug and Play PHP/MySQL User Management/Login/Security System

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone recommend a plug and play PHP/MySQL software that will enable me to manage users, protect pages, prompt for logins, handle lost passwords, store their info such as name/addy/email etc.

Does anything like that exist?

Preferably, I'd like it to be as easy as including a file in my existing pages to make them a part of the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used Pear::Auth to achieve this end (building custom CMS) with some success.  There is another package that has more features called LiveUser.

They both have methods for creating/deleting users (in mySql), storing sessions, and accessing session data, so they do quite a bit of the heavy lifting for you.  That said, neither of these packages are "plug-and-play," but they're about as close as your going to get to your stated goal without using some kind of premade CMS.

Pear packages are not very well documented as a whole, but the Auth docs aren't that bad, and there are some useful examples out there.  This is the one I worked from:
http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/pear-auth-example-94752.html

Answer (score 0):

Erm... [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) and its half a billion extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Drupal, Joomla, (As mentioned) Wordpress. Basically you simply want a CMS without any pages.

Comment: Ive logged many many hours using wordpress, however i need something more lightweight to plug into my existing site/program.

Comment: I'll agree with you there. I've heard a lot of complaints that Wordpress takes up a lot of resources. Yet everyone still uses it. meh.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not gonna use WordPress, Joomla or something to fulfil your project needs, I recommend you to google for some membership system scripts & tutorials and attach 'em to your existing project. for example take a look at these:

> http://evolt.org/PHP-Login-System-with-Admin-Features
>   http://gigaspartan.com/?p=6
>   http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/Creating-a-Membership-System/

and [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20membership%20system) of course.
Also using the `Pear` packages could be a better & more reliable solution.

As a whole no one could find any other programmer's code to fully match his/her codes. So we have to adapt ourselves to the best cms/frameworks available, I think. WordPress is pretty easy to start with:

```
require './wp-blog-header.php';
//and your story begins!
```

Also this [article](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/use-wordpress-as-a-php-framework-for-your-static-html-pages/) worth a look.